# For every n ∈ N, prove that $(1 − 1/2 )(1 − 1/2^2 ). . .(1 − 1/2^n ) ≥ 1/4 + 1/2^{n+1}$ through induction.

Tags: proof-verification, induction

this is a homework question for my university math proofs. I've spent over an hour and cannot figure it out. For this induction proof I understand the base case but can't seem to solve the inductive step.

Base case: $n = 1$

$(1 − 1/2 )≥ 1/4 + 1/2^{1+1}.\;$     Thus, the base case is true ($1/2 = 1/2$)

Inductive case: $P(n) \Rightarrow P(n+1)$
Direct proof:  Assume $P(n)$, show $P(n+1)$.

Suppose $P(n): (1 − 1/2 )(1 − 1/2^2 ). . .(1 − 1/2^n ) ≥ 1/4 + 1/2^{n+1}$.

If I multiply both sides by $(1 − 1/2^{(n+1)+1})$, the new LHS of $P(n)$ will be equal to $P(n+1)$, and I can try to show that the new RHS of $P(n)$ is equivalent to the RHS of $P(n+1)$.

New RHS of P(n):  $(1/4 + 1/2^{n+1})*(1 − 1/2^{(n+1)+1})$

Now when I expand this out I can't seem to show that it is equivalent to what the RHS of $P(n+1)$ was.

Is my approach correct?

Thanks,
John

Comment: Apologies for not using Latex not accepted. Welcome to MSE! Please take a moment to find out how to format your questions in mathematical typesetting. As written now, chances are you will get little to no attention.

Comment: @uniquesolution Good point, but link [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: To the OP: two things will get you started with TeX here: 1) Put dollar signs around your math expressions, and 2) Use curly brackets instead of parentheses to set off exponents that consist of more than a single character, e.g. the final term "(1-1/2^((n+1)+1))" needs to be "(1-1/2^{(n+1)+1})" to make it turn out (once you have it inside dollar signs) as $(1-1/2^{(n+1)+1})$ instead of $(1-1/2^((n+1)+1))$.

Comment: Thanks for resources! and @uniquesolution yeah it would be good if you posted a link of where to find it instead of just saying I can't do it.

Comment: Thanks @Barry Cipra I fixed the formatting

Comment: @JohnTopham, you're welcome.  But you might want to just rollback to your version before Bernard's edit. It looks like the exponents were correctly inside curly brackets there. (Ah, never mind, it looks like Bernard has fixed everything.)

Comment: Best way to learn mathjax (or really just math in latex) is to find a question or answer that has the formatting you want and then click to edit. You will see how they produced the formatting (just make sure you discard your edits). You can also refer to any [math latex](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics) reference (it doesn't have to be that one).

Comment: @Jared, I'm not sure of this, but a new user may not be allowed to click to edit. But I think they can examine source code in posts that have an edit history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in your approach is easily corrected: For the LHS to go from

$$(1-1/2)(1-1/2^2)\cdots(1-1/2^n)$$

to

$$(1-1/2)(1-1/2^2)\cdots(1-1/2^{n+1})$$

you want to multiply by $(1-1/2^{n+1})$, not $(1-1/2^{(n+1)+1})$. From there it's fairly straightforward to show that

$$\begin{align}
\left({1\over4}+{1\over2^{n+1}}\right)\left(1-{1\over2^{n+1}}\right)
&={1\over4}+{1\over2^{n+1}}\left(1-{1\over4}-{1\over2^{n+1}}\right)\\
&\ge{1\over4}+{1\over2^{n+1}}\cdot{1\over2}\quad\text{if }n\ge1\\
&={1\over4}+{1\over2^{(n+1)+1}}
\end{align}$$

(Thanks to user StAKmod for pointing out an error in my first attempt at fair straightforwardness.)

Comment: actually,it can be equal,consider $n=1$

Comment: @StAKmod, yikes, you're right. I was too quick to drop the $1/2^{2n+2}$. Sorry, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

your thought was right,except for trying to prove them equal,what we usually do here is to prove $\geqslant$.
So $$\prod_{i=0}^n (1-{1\over 2^i})*(1-{1\over 2^{n+1}})\geqslant(1-{1\over 2^{n+1}})*({1\over 4}+{1\over 2^{n+1}})$$
simplify and get${1\over 4}+{1\over 2^{n+2}}+({1\over 2^{n+2}}-{1\over 2^{n+3}}-{1\over 2^{2n+2}})$

What is left is to prove the part in the bracket is $\geqslant0$.
Which is simple,for${1\over 2^{n+2}}-{1\over 2^{n+3}}-{1\over 2^{2n+2}}={1\over 2^{n+3}}-{1\over 2^{2n+2}}$  and the fact $n\geqslant1$

Comment: Good answer. I think you mean $\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2^{n + 1}} + (\dots)$.

Comment: Actually no,you see I took ${1\over 2^{n+1}}$ into 2 halfs

Comment: Ahh I see, yes. That's why I commented--wasn't sure.

Comment: when you say "which is simple for.. " I dont actually get how that equality is true

Comment: $n\geqslant1$ is equal to $2n+2\geqslant n+3$,so $2^{2n+2}\geqslant 2^{n+3}$